# Midlet signed with verisign securityexception in S40

Tags: java-me, midlet, securityexception, nokia-s40, verisign

I signed a midlet with a verisign certificate.  In other devices works well, but in a Nokia 2710 S40, I get SecurityException: Permission Denied each time the application does an httpconnection.

I have already tried with all the permissions in Options>Application Access>Communication>Network Access, but It doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved.  I had to add the API permissions in the jad file.